# Android GoogleMaps v2 Scroll limit

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I have offline map implemented on GoogleMap (tilesOverly) Everything working fine just the problem is i can scroll outside the offline map.

How i can close the map to BoundBox like in  osmdroid scrollAreaLimit?

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way currently available to us is to have `OnCameraChangeListener`, where you check if `CameraPosition.target` is outside of your defined `LatLngBounds` and doing `GoogleMap.animateCamera` to a position inside the bounds.

See this video for how it behaves: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-nCZ37HdheY

Comment: Thx, this is what i try but little ugly because i can see the gray place :)

Comment: @Sherad The video shows white tiles outside. I suggest choosing some color for your app and doing the same. I guess users will tend to try to counter your limitation, but not for too long. Panning the map and seeing to goes back is fun, but not longer than few minutes.